# Why Date class does not support Internationalization?

Tags: java, date, datetime, deprecated, java.util.date

I was going through the different ways that we can get **Date and Time** in java, while reading the documentation could not understand what the below quote mean.

> Unfortunately, the API for these functions was not amenable to internationalization.

The above quote is from documentation of Date class of java.
What does that mean ??
Is this the reason why the methods of the Date class were deprecated?

Comment: You should be using Local or Zoned Date classes, not `java.util.Date` / Calendar

Comment: BTW `java.util.Date` was almost  completely replaced by `Calendar` as of Java 1.1 (one-point-one, not to be confused with Java 11); and these were all outdated by classes in the `java.time` package with Java 8 (year 2014)

Comment: As @OneCricketeer said, don’t use `Date`. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). So you need not know the answer to your question. In any case they referred both to lacking support for locales (for example languages, date formats and definitions of week numbers), time zones and probably more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use only *java.time* classes. Never use `Date`/`Calendar` etc.

```java
ZonedDateTime.now(
                ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" )
        )
        .format(
                DateTimeFormatter
                        .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
                        .withLocale( Locale.GERMANY )
        )
```

> Sonntag, 7. Mai 2023, 04:53:02 Japanische Normalzeit

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You asked:

> Is this the reason why the methods of the Date class were deprecated?

The legacy date-time classes are rife with poor design decisions, written by people who did not understand date-time handling. The lack of internationalization is but one of *many* problems.

Trying to understand these legacy classes is a waste of time, unless you want lessons on how to *not* do proper object-oriented programming. These classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Use neither of the two `Date` classes, nor `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `GregorianCalendar`, etc.  Use only the date-time classes from the *java.time* package. Focus your precious learning time on *java.time*.

## *java.time*

The *java.time* classes provide [internationalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) through the  [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

In modern Java, the localization information comes from the [*Common Locale Data Repository Project (CLDR)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) published by the [Unicode Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Consortium).

Here is some example code.

Capture the current moment as seen in the [wall-clock time/calendar used by the people of Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan_Standard_Time). For this purpose, use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class. Specify the time zone of interest by using the [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) class.

```java
ZoneId zoneIdTokyo = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" );
ZonedDateTime zdtTokyo = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneIdTokyo );
```

Generate text representing that moment using [French Canadian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Canadians) localization (human language & cultural norms).

```java
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;
DateTimeFormatter formatter =
        DateTimeFormatter
                .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
                .withLocale( locale );
String output = zdtTokyo.format( formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( "zdtTokyo.toString() = " + zdtTokyo );
System.out.println( "output = " + output );
```

When run:

```
zdtTokyo.toString() = 2023-05-07T04:47:54.551174+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]
output = dimanche 7 mai 2023, 04 h 47 min 54 s heure normale du Japon
```

Comment: Very nice demonstration of internationalization offered by java.time! Nothing you could ever have done with the old `Date` class alone, no way.

Comment: One may add that other aspects of internationalization are provided by [ZoneId](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html), [`WeekFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) and [`Chronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/Chronology.html) (not meant as an exhaustive list).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the suggested replacements, you'll see there are two - Calendar and GregorianCalendar.

The programmer needs to make a choice, depending on the intention of the code. The old API would have been one or the other.  That is, it "did not support internationalization".

Comment: This answer was long outdated before it was written. `Calendar` and `GregorianClaendar` were obsoleted by [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) with Java 8 more than 9 years ago. Although historically they did replace much of the functionality of `Date` back in 1997, more than 25 years ago.

Comment: Sure, but the question is, why were Date methods deprecated.  Not why was the thing that replaced the Date methods deprecated.

Comment: Yeah, true. And one of the many typical mistakes people made with them was to use one of the `Calendar.getInstance` methods and assume they got a Gregorian calendar without ever checking their assumption. It’s very good that we don’t use those anymore.

Comment: I rather wish some of the ancient classes, that are essentially 99% deprecated, would just cease to exist.  Sure, it would be a temporary problem for upgraders, but on the plus side, there would be fewer "don't use that, use this" traps for new programmers.  But what do I know?  I'm still using Java 11 :-)